# How to get full detail about a file, when I have its content uri?

Tags: android, mediastore

I now have a uri like `content://media/external/images/media/161596`. I wanted know its complete details like Title, Mimetype, Artist etc. I was hoping for something like `MediaStore.MediaColumns.URI`. But I didn't get that. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!. The last digits in the uri actually indicates the id of the media. So you can query with selection as `MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID='161596'`.